# How to generate a download request from html page to controller of spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Student Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h3 align="center">New Trainee Registration</h3>
 
     <table align="center" cellpadding="10">

      <!-- First Name -->
      <tr>
       <td>First Name</td>
       <td>${traineeData.fName}</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Last Name -->
      <tr>
       <td>Last Name</td>
       <td>${traineeData.lName}</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Father's Name -->
      <tr>
       <td>Father's Name</td>
       <td>${traineeData.fatherName}</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Mobile Number -->
      <tr>
       <td>Mobile No.</td>
       <td>${traineeData.mobile}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Joining Date</td>
       <td>${traineeData.joiningDate}></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Grade</td>
       <td>${traineeData.grade}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Gender</td>
       <td>${traineeData.gender}</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Course -->
      <tr>
       <td>COURSES<br />APPLIED FOR
       </td>
       <td>${traineeData.course}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Joining Date</td>
       <td>${traineeData.joiningDate}</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- Submit and Reset -->
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <button type="button" >Generate Certificate</button>
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say, I have a download button on my HTML page. when clicking on this button a request goes through the controller of the spring MVC framework along with "enrollmentNo".

On Controller class, I will use this enrollmentNo.

I have a class which will generate a certificate for the student by fetching data using the student's enrollmentNo.

and response goes back and a file will download(which a pdf file generated by my pre-created class)

I have tried with many ways but not get what I want.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateCertificate")
public void generateCertificate(@RequestParam("traineeData.enrollmentNo") int enrollmentNo) {

    System.out.println("you in /generateCertificate");

    // I don't know what should I return... 
    // please change return type accordingly...
}
```

I want a button on my HTML page named "Generate certificate".  The code should be easy and normal, Ajax can be used here.

Comment: So, what is the problem that you're facing?  Like, what isn't working correctly?

Comment: I'm unable to reach the controller from the html page. and also don't know what should I return so that generated certificate gets downloaded.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you please post the html that is supposed to be calling your controller?

Comment: I have added the code in the question please fine.

Comment: Well, that makes things more clear, thanks for adding the html.  The button isn't actually doing anything.  It just exists.  Do you want a form to be submitted?  Do you want javascript to execute?  This might turn into multiple stack overflow questions btw...

Comment: I have tried much code on the button tag but nothing works. can you help me by writing some code here?  Please. I'm a beginner. I have found many codes on the internet but I was unable to understand.

Comment: I'm just trying to view details here. Now I put a button here which will generate a certificate for this trainee. by clicking this button a certificate will generate by using this enrollmentNo.

Comment: FYI, I have tried to update the formatting and spelling mistakes in your code above.  So, the answer below might not totally work in your environment.

Comment: @PrinceKumar; are you using Spring Data by any chance?  If so there are ways of doing this sort of thing without much code at all.  Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button isn't actually doing anything, useful.

Try this code around your button...

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <form action="/generateCertificate" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="enrollmentNo" value="${traineeData.enrollmentNo}"
            <button type="submit">Generate Certificate</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then your controller will need to changed slightly...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateCertificate")
public void generateCertificate(@RequestParam("enrollmentNo") int enrollmentNo) {

    // The @RequestParam was changed to the name of the param from the form and not the object/value.
}
```

Comment: I finally generated the certificate in a directory(say, D directory) and thank you for the help...
Now can you help me to download this certificate on the same "Generate Certificate" button?

Comment: I would ask a new stack overflow question for your new question.

Comment: Dear hooknc, as per my question, your ans still incomplete.... I asked to generate download request.... But helped me in half... I just reached on the controller.... But still file download work is on pending...

Comment: Please help me to download the generated certificate (PDF format) from the same button.

Comment: Post the code that generates the pdf.  And show us what you have for downloading the file.  We'll be able to help you from there.  :)